# Request not working for a specific URL?

Tags: php, curl, vine

I'm executing this curl post as below:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://api.vineapp.com/users/authenticate';


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=email@example.com&password=password');


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

when running this on my **local machine using mamp it returns successfully** with a json string like this:

```
{"code": "", "data": {"username": "InstaBrand", "edition": "US", "userId": 1123456, "key": "key-value-string", "avatarUrl": "http://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/21F43610771076328335136776192_263ec9b0577.0.2.jpg?versionId=nWh0YVdjXW2oxz0P7dild3Q5A4D5M53G"}, "success": true, "error": ""}
```

When running `curl_getinfo` it shows this info:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.vineapp.com/users/authenticate
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 260
    [request_size] => 197
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.105723
    [namelookup_time] => 0.486254
    [connect_time] => 0.620647
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.925538
    [size_upload] => 55
    [size_download] => 333
    [speed_download] => 301
    [speed_upload] => 49
    [download_content_length] => 333
    [upload_content_length] => 55
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.10562
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 23.21.154.247
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.15.128
    [local_port] => 57522
)
```

However when I **execute this on my server it returns a 500** error and this info is returned from `curl_getinfo`:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.vineapp.com/users/authenticate
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 500
    [header_size] => 131
    [request_size] => 197
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.049556
    [namelookup_time] => 0.017791
    [connect_time] => 0.019114
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.047803
    [size_upload] => 55
    [size_download] => 87
    [speed_download] => 42
    [speed_upload] => 26
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 2.049474
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Trouble shooting done:

1. change URL being requested on server to a different HTTPS URL = successful response
2. made sure both environments are running same php version
3. made sure php and curl `timeout`, curl `connectiontimeout`, and php `max execution time` has plenty of time

Does any one know why this might be happening, or have had similar issues with different environments?

Comment: Can your server be banned on remote server?

Comment: Does your server have a security certificate setup to use the https protocol?

Comment: Cheery, I don't think it is because it's never made one successful request to that api before.. Larry, as for security certificate it does not have this setup, however it is able to make api request to other https servers such as facebook, google etc.